# Implementing GTA5-parallax-pen from codepen

Tags: javascript, css, html, parallax

I found this neat pen on codepen http://codepen.io/simooo/pen/egatA and wanted to implement it on my website. But somehow I can't get it working. I tried also using only the code (with html5 markup) but that didn't help either.
I copied it to jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net/2mm6u/), to see if I could find the problem experimenting with it but the Fiddle also doesn't work.

So I hope to find some help here, as I'm new to the whole parallax-effects.

Comment: Open the developer console. You will see many errors (move your mouse over the image)!

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2mm6u/4/) is a fixed version. The problem was that you didn't include KnockoutJS as an external resource.

Comment: Thanks ComFreek, sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the console error:

```
ReferenceError: ko is not defined
```

You're missing knockout js. Include it in your fiddle and it will work fine.

Also I think you might have a typo when declaring your global variable `parallax`:

```
var parallx = null; // Should be parallax?
```